# Error 1004 caused by =?

Tags: excel, vba

I have checked a lot of different solutions here on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me.

When I insert a value like "1" everything works, but When I try to insert my formula I always get a runtime error. Does anyone have an explanation? Would be very thankful for any help!

```
Sub test()


Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim wsWithSheetNames As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook

Set wsWithSheetNames = ActiveSheet
Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook


For wsname = 1 To 254
For Each cell In wsWithSheetNames.Range("A" & wsname)
With wbToAddSheetsTo
    .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
    wsname2 = cell.Value
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
      Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
Next cell

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1", "B1735").Copy 
Worksheets(wsname2).Range("A2")
(HERE IS THE PROBLEM!)Worksheets(wsname2).Range("B2:AGR1736").FormulaLocal = 
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,OFFSET([final.xlsb]" & CHr(34) & wsname2 & Chr(34) & "!$A$1:$D$2000,0,
(COLUMN(A2)*4-4)),4,0),"")"


Next wsname


End Sub
```

EDIT: changed the line to:

```
Worksheets(wsname2).Range("B2:AGR1736").FormulaLocal = 
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,OFFSET([final.xlsb]" & wsname2 & "!$A$1:$D$2000,0,
(COLUMN(A2)*4-4)),4,0)," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"
```

If I dont write the "=" the code works just fine, why is it not working with the "="?

Comment: if you put the = sign the text is interpreted as a formula and excel will execute it and in your case excel finds an error with your formula hence the error code 1004. if you don't put the = sign, the text is considered as text and this will not give problem. use it as a basis to track the error in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to declare wsname and wsname 2, so the full code would be like this:

```
Sub test()

Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim wsWithSheetNames As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsname As Integer
Dim wsname2 As String

Set wsWithSheetNames = ActiveSheet
Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook


For wsname = 1 To 254
For Each cell In wsWithSheetNames.Range("A" & wsname)
With wbToAddSheetsTo
    .Sheets.Add After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
    wsname2 = cell.Value
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
      Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
Next cell

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1", "B1735").Copy Worksheets(wsname2).Range("A2")
'Worksheets(wsname2).Range("B2:AGR1736").FormulaLocal = 
'"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,OFFSET([final.xlsb]" & CHr(34) & wsname2 & Chr(34) & "!$A$1:$D$2000,0,
'(COLUMN(A2)*4-4)),4,0),"")"

Worksheets(wsname2).Range("B2:AGR1736") = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,OFFSET([final.xlsb]" & wsname2 & "!$A$1:$D$2000,0," & "(COLUMN(A2)*4-4)),4,0)," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"


Next wsname


End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I tried it this way but I still get the same error. I dont understand it, all I want to do is insert the formula as a value. How can this not work?

Comment: Could you please let me know what the final.xlsb is?

Comment: final.xlsb has values in it. both files have dates, the vlookup checkes sheetname and for the values that correspond with the dates/sheetname.

Comment: Please change my code Worksheets(wsname2).Range("B2:AGR1736").FormulaLocal = 
"=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,OFFSET([final.xlsb]" & CHr(34) & wsname2 & Chr(34) & "!$A$1:$D$2000,0,
(COLUMN(A2)*4-4)),4,0),"")"  to Worksheets(wsname2).Range("B2:AGR1736") = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,OFFSET([final.xlsb]" & wsname2 & "!$A$1:$D$2000,0," & "(COLUMN(A2)*4-4)),4,0)," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")"

Comment: An alternate is to use `TEXT(,)` instead of `""`.